Is there a count-based window in Apache Flink?
I am writing code for data stream processing in Apache Flink, but I am having trouble finding any mention of count-based windows in the Apache Flink documentation.
I checked the link below, but it looks like there are only time-based windows.
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.19/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/

I think it exists. There is at least .countWindow() for keyed streams and .countWindowAll() for non-keyed. There is an example WindowWordCount provided by Flink developers.
countWindow(size: Long):

Windows this KeyedStream into tumbling count windows.
Params:
size – The size of the windows in number of elements.

countWindow(size: Long, slide: Long):

Windows this KeyedStream into sliding count windows.
Params:
size – The size of the windows in number of elements.
slide – The slide interval in number of elements.

I never used it myself but I hope it's what you are looking for.

That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!
